# Error while using the closure in groovy

Tags: groovy

I am new too the groovy. I have simple code to learn the groovy closures.
My code is

```
class function1{

        static void main(def args){
                square = {it * it}
                [1,2,3].each(square);
        }
}
```

So, output of the program should like `1,4,9`. But I am getting error as

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/home/xxx/GroovyTest/example2.groovy: 4: Apparent variable 'square' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'square' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
 @ line 4, column 3.
                square = {it * it}
     ^

/home/xxx/GroovyTest/example2.groovy: 5: Apparent variable 'square' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'square' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
 @ line 5, column 16.
                [1,2,3].each(square)
                  ^

2 errors
```

I am not getting how variable square found in static scope.

Thank you

Comment: Also, classes should have capitalized names `class Function1`

Comment: and just `static main( args ) {` will do in Groovy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `def` keyword:

```
 static void main(def args){
     def square = {it * it}
     [1,2,3].each(square);
 }
```

Comment: @Optimus, @IgorArtamonov, i'd like to add: you can only use undeclared variables (i.e., without `def` or explicit typing) when using [scripts](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Scripts%2Band%2BClasses). You can [code this behavior](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using%2BinvokeMethod%2Band%2BgetProperty) yourself, also.